# Get the luminosity of a pixel area in Swift

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I would like to read the average luminosity of a section of the screen intended as the sum of components. I am capturing the screen in the way:

```
func beginSession() {
    do{
        try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
        if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession){
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
            previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame
            captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

}

func processPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer: CVImageBufferRef) {
    let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer);
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);
    let pixels = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer))
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)
    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(UnsafeMutablePointer(pixel), 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)
    let total = width * height;
    var light=0
    // ??
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );
}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    if let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer){
    /*Lock the image buffer*/
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
    /*Get information about the image*/
        processPixelBuffer(imageBuffer)
    }
}
```

How do I copy a part of the screen into a buffer and then check each of its element to asses their color components.

Comment: As a matter of fact I would need to receive an event when the luminosity of an area changes. I found the solution at: https://github.com/schneiderandre/ASCScreenBrightnessDetector that detects changes of luminosity in the whole screen; instead I would like to receive it for a specific part and possibly as fast as possible.

Comment: Moreover that solution checks the front screen while I would like to use the rear camera.